# Analysing the modes of a signal with Laplace transform

Tags: dynamical-systems, laplace-transform, signal-processing

If I have a linear dynamical system (assume continuous time for the time being) I can create the transfer function, let's say:
$$\frac{1}{(s+a_1)(s+a_2)}$$
 and the [pole-zero map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cabJ.png) (this one is for e.g. $-2\pm i$), then I can construct the output signal with the given modes for a given input.

Now, I would like to do the opposite, I have an unknown system, and by having the input and output data I want to work out the system transfer function (at least the dominant modes). Kind of doing a Fourier transform, but I'm also interested in the damping, not just the frequency components.

I was thinking on applying the Laplace transform 
$$F(s)=\int _{0}^{\infty }e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$$
then finding the singularities of $F(s)$ would give the answer (i.e. the same pole-zero map, that is shown above.

However due to region of convergence (ROC) issues of the Laplace integral (it is only valid for $\Re(s)>-2$), it doesn't give a sensible result. See [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae3sL.png).

So my question is, why is this? Also, why can the signal (or system) be analysed on the whole s-plane (for finding the poles for example), when the ROC is much smaller? For example if $a_1=-1$, $a_2=-2$, then the ROC is $\Re(s)>-1$, but we still work with the pole at $-2$.

Thanks

Comment: if you know that your transfer functions is mostly rational, then you can write $f(t)$ as $h(t) + \sum_n a_n e^{\rho_n t} t^{k_n} 1_{t > 0}$ with $h(t)$ very small, corresponding to the transfer function $H(s) + \sum_n a_n \frac{1}{(s-\rho_n)^{k_n+1}}$, and you can iteratively detect and substract the dominating pole (the $\rho$ with largest real part)

Comment: Thanks! Then how do I decompose $f(t)$ to the sum of those exponentials?